# Counting number of days in transaction data but from 6AM to 6AM of next day in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have transaction data but I need to calculate the number of visits based on `countDistinct` of dates. The problem is that I need to calculate it based on a timestamp of 6AM to 6AM, i.e. if the transaction happens on 04/07 between 12 AM and 6AM, it still should be counted as a single visit.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

```
CUSTOMER_ID   TRANSACTION_ID   TRANSACTION_DATETIME

     C1             T1           04/07/2019 22:20:00
     C1             T1           04/08/2019 1:00:00
     C1             T2           04/07/2019 17:10:00
     C1             T3           05/08/2019 12:00:00
```

So as per the above, I need the visits for each customer_ID.

This is the code I have so far

```
testdfmod = df.groupBy("CUSTOMER_ID") \
                           .agg(F.max(F.col('TRANSACTION_DATETIME')).alias("TRANSACTION_DATETIME"), \
                    F.countDistinct(
                                    F.to_date(F.col('TRANSACTION_DATETIME')).alias('TRANSACTION_DATETIME').cast("date")) \
                           .alias("TOTAL_TRIPS"))
```

Thank you so much for all the help.

Comment: Is `TRANSACTION_ID` column present in the data? If yes, then isn't that your answer?

Comment: Nope, that is not my answer... considering the fact that I might have a transaction between 12 AM and 6 AM of the next day, it does not work correctly. Say I have someone coming at 10 PM and then doing another transaction at 1 AM, then according to the above, it becomes 2 visits, but according to my requirement it should be treated as a single visit., if you get what I am trying to say.

Comment: @mayankagrawal, can you please also let me know why you downvoted this question?

Comment: Got it! I didn't downvote your question @Manas. Probably someone who couldn't understand your question, although it looks clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can just add a new column with value equals to TRANSACTION_DATETIME minus 6 hours (6*3600 seconds):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn('adjusted_trx_date', F.from_unixtime(F.unix_timestamp('TRANSACTION_DATETIME', format='MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss')-6*3600, format='yyyy-MM-dd')).show()
#+-----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+
#|CUSTOMER_ID|TRANSACTION_ID|TRANSACTION_DATETIME|adjusted_trx_date|
#+-----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+
#|         C1|            T1| 04/07/2019 22:20:00|       2019-04-07|
#|         C1|            T1|  04/08/2019 1:00:00|       2019-04-07|
#|         C1|            T2| 04/07/2019 17:10:00|       2019-04-07|
#|         C1|            T3| 05/08/2019 12:00:00|       2019-05-08|
#+-----------+--------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

Then you can do countDistinct() on the new column `adjusted_trx_date` with the code you had.